# HTML5 geolocation does not work with GPS in stock browser

Tags: geolocation, stock-browser, motorola-xoom

I am using a Motorola XOOM2 ME with Android 3.2.2.

Location settings are: no Wifi as source, but GPS as source enabled. Browser is allowed to access location.

If I go to maps.google.com in the Android stock browser, Google Maps cannot get a location. If I go to maps.google.com in Opera Mobile, Google Maps can get a precise location.

If I enable Wifi as a location source, Google Maps can get a location in the stock browser but it is very imprecise.

Using GPS status the GPS itself seems to operate fine.

What could be going on here? I am really out of ideas. TIA.